# JQuery Droppable in Drop-Function wait until Button is klicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

i use sortable's & Droppables to receive elements from a draggable list. As soon as the update function is executed a modal opens. I want to achieve that the update function is interrupted and waits until a button is clicked in the modal. I have no idea how to achieve this. Thanks a lot. This is my Droppable-List:

```
$("#myUL2").droppable({
    accept: "#myUL li",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        //open Modal
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');            
        //wait until Button in Modal is klicked
        //More Code
}
```

This is my Button in the Modal:

```
$(".baugruppe").click(function() {
    //things need to be done before the drop function continues
});
```

Comment: Can you not move the things you want to do after the button is clicked out of the drop function into a different function and just call that one, when clicking the button?

Comment: I need to access the ui item. var draggable = ui.draggable to adjust the draggable.

Comment: You could save the ui item in a variable, which you set in the beginning of the file (like `let uiVariable`), and then set the value of that variable in the drop function and access that variable, when clicking the button, to get the ui item in a different function.

Comment: It's working. Thank you! I'm stupid